# I want to display the zero in front of a phone number/ number

Tags: python

What I put in python:

```
phoneNumber = input("Enter your Phone Number: ")

print("Your number is", str(phoneNumber))
```

What I get if I put 021999888:

```
Enter your Phone Number: 021999888
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "None", line 1, in 
>   invalid token: , line 1, pos 9

What I get if I put 21:

> Enter your Phone Number: 21
>
> Your Number is 21

What I get if I put 02:

> Enter your Phone Number: 02
>
> Your Number is 2

What I get if I put 021:

> Enter your Phone Number: 021
>
> Your Number is 17

What I get if I put 09:

```
Enter your Phone Number: 09

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "None", line 1, in <module>
invalid token: <string>, line 1, pos 2
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Use `raw_input` not `input`.

Comment: It looks like you're using Python 3 instead of Python 2 - I say this because of your `print` function. In Python 2, `input` would actually execute the string as Python code, whereas in Python 3, `input` is the  same as `raw_input` was in Python 2.  Could you clarify which version you're using?

Comment: @Makoto, It would have to be python2 because if it was python3, it wouldn't raise an error since input would make it a string.

Comment: You're right, but it's better to be explicit about it than not.

Comment: @Makoto It is possible to use `print()` in Python 2: `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary:  Yes, I'm well aware of that.  Again - it's better to be explicit rather than implicit.

Comment: thank you guys, its all solved with the raw_input function,
Thanks for you time

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `0` before a numeric literal, then it is in octal format. In this case any digit greater than 7 will result in an error. I think you should consider storing the phone number as a string, so use `raw_input()` instead. This will also keep the leading 0's.

Comment: And since this is confusing behavior, the `0`-prefix notation for octals has been made illegal in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

A `0` before a number is in octal format:

```
>>> 02
2
>>> 021
17
>>> 0562
370
>>> 02412
1290
>>> oct(1)
'01'
>>> oct(1290)
'02412'
```

Using `raw_input()` instead makes sure that the input doesn't have to be something you can call in a shell:

```
>>> number = raw_input('Enter your phone number: ')
Enter your phone number: 04081546723
>>> number
'04081546723'
```

If you call `021999888` in a shell, here is what happens:

```
>>> 021999888
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    021999888
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) for more information on octal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

@perreal is right. You should use `raw_input` instead:

```
>>> phoneNumber = raw_input("Enter your Phone Number: ")
>>> print("Your number is", phoneNumber)
Enter your Phone Number: 091234123
Your number is 091234123
```